# Multiple IF AND statements in Excel

Tags: excel, xlsx

How would I combine both of these points into one nestled IF AND statement all in one column?

1. If B6 is "Alone" and N6 is >= 20 then "Donor" if not "Single"
2. If B6 is "Partnered" and N6 is >= 20 "Charity" if not "Frugal"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If B6 is "Alone" and N6 is >= 20 then "Donor" if not "Single"

```
 =if(and(B6="Alone",N6>=20),"Donor","Single")
```

If B6 is "Partnered" and N6 is >= 20 "Charity" if not "Frugal"

```
 =if(and(B6="Partnered",N6>=20), "Charity", "Frugal")
```

If you need to combine multiple if's (more than two possibilities):

```
=if(condition1,true value,if(condition2, true value, false value))
```

But I didn't see anything that had that type of logic chain in your example.

-- Edit --

Okay, now I see what you are trying to do.  Try this:

```
=IF(B6="Alone",IF(N6>=20,"Donor","Single"),IF(B6="Partnered",
    IF(N6>=20,"Charity","Frugal"),""))
```

Comment: What if I wanted those two IF statements to become combined in one column?

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't terribly clear in my question. I've tried your edited function but I always get stuck at the fourth outcome since it has to be "Alone" and >=20 is "donor" and <20 "Single" and then "Partnered" >=20 "Charity" and <20 "Frugal". I'm quite new to excel so I'm sorry if I don't make sense.

Comment: I just made an edit; my fault.  I typed before I tested.  I actually tested this one this time.

Comment: Thank you so much for you're answer you've helped me greatly!